# LVM on LUKS with multiple drives

Tags: lvm, luks

Is it possible to setup a LVM on LUKS system using multiple hard drives and not enter a passphrase for each drive?

In the past, I've done LUKS on LVM and had the key-files for other volumes on the root volume.  Unlock the root volume and crypttab unlocks all the rest.  But this has been cumbersome to maintain.

Comment: You might explain what is cumbersome about that.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same metadata (LUKS headers) for most of my encrypted volumes. If that is true for your volumes, too, or if you are willing to change it accordingly then you could use a script which just reads the DM device table information from the root volume and sets up the other devices with the same data.